# Property [path] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to show uploaded pictures of users at my Blade, so I added this:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    @if($user->photo_id)
       <td class="center">
          <img src="{{ $user->photos->path }}" width="80">
       </td>
    @else
       <td class="center">
    
       </td>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

But it returns this error:

> **Exception** Property [path] does not exist on this collection instance.

I have already added these relationships to the Models as well:

`Photo.php`:

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

`User.php`:

```
public function photos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Photo::class);
    }
```

So what is going wrong here ? How can I solve this issue ?

Also when I say: `{{ dd($user->photos) }}`, it retuns:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1231 ▼
  #items: []
}
```

And here is also table `photos`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your User model, you defined one to many relationship. So laravel will return an array of collection.

If you path will not be in array, I suggest you to change the relation to one-to-one.

`User.php`

```
public function photos()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Photo::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you defined your one to many relationship contrariwise.
You're getting multiple photos for a user. So, it is normal to get a collection of photos instead of an instance of photo.

In the result, you don't have *path* property on photos collection, probably you can handle this error by getting first instance `$user->photos->first()->path`, but you need to have a clear definition for your model relationship.